# How to run cucumber feature files in customized order using maven commands in cmd in windows using Junit or java commands

Tags: windows, maven, cmd, cucumber

i have a text file which contains the run order of feature files like f1.feature, f2.feature.....,
but i don't know how to force maven to run that file in cmd in windows, using cucumber Junit or java commands.

Answer (score 0):

Since your scenarios should be able to run independent of each other, Cucumber does not support specifying the order in which features should run.
Making sure your scenario's are independent and do not influence each other, will revent you a lot of flakyness and headaches in the future!

That said, the features run in alphabetic order.